# How to get authentication token programmatically using facebook api?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app in facebook and I have AppID and AppSecret keys.  Now I want to get the authentication token for that app.  I can use the graph api tool provided by facebook to get the token but I want to get the token programmatically using facebook api.  Also I want to get the token without logging in to the facebook account actually.  Is there any way to get it 
programmatically using facebook api?

Answer (score 0):

As far as know, you can't get it without actually logging to Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate a long-lived access token without going through Facebook's OAuth process (the Graph Explorer tool token expires after two hours).

The OAuth process can be automated to an extent, but there is one part that requires the user to click a button to authorize your application to access their Facebook account. Facebook OAuth is therefore a two step process:

1. Show the authorization URL and get the user to click 'allow'
2. Retrieve the access token once the user has clicked 'allow'

The Temboo SDK breaks the Facebook OAuth process down in to two steps - `InitializeOAuth` and `FinalizeOAuth` - that you can use in your app. These steps map to the process I outlined above. You can learn more about how to handle Facebook OAuth via Temboo [here](https://www.temboo.com/library/Library/Facebook/OAuth/). To see this behavior in action you can check out a live example (with source code available) on the Temboo [examples](https://www.temboo.com/examples) page.

(Full disclosure: I work at Temboo)

Answer (score 0):

NO, you can't have long lived access token without login in Facebook, because for long lived access token you need to have short lived access token  which you will be needed in below Facebook graph API:

**STEPS FOR LASTING PAGE ACCESS TOKEN**

1- You have to get page access token for a user by this API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{User-id}/accounts?access_token={access-token}
```

2- Then u have to refresh the save token by below API which will last for 60 days:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={your-client-id}&client_secret={client-secret}&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token={previous-access-token}
```